# Cookie Script for remembering lanuage setting website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

i found this code on stackoverflow for a website translation but when i use it, the website flickers like it is going to the same/or other page every millisecond.

I am using this script :

```
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script>
                $(function () {

        var url = 'http://www.gester.nl';
        var english_page = 'index-eng';
        var dutch_page = 'index';


        if ($.cookie('default_page') != null) {
            if (window.location.href != url + '/' + $.cookie('default_page')) {
                window.location.href = url + '/' + $.cookie('default_page');
            }
        }

        $('#english').click(function () {
            $.cookie('default_page', dutch_page, { expires: 999 });
            alert('Dutch was set as the default language');
        });

            $('#dutch').click(function () {
            $.cookie('default_page', dutch_page, { expires: 999 });
            alert('Dutch was set as the default language');
        });

    });</script> </head>
```

i am using this code for my image button:

```
<a href="index"><img id="dutch" src="images/dutch.png"></a>
```

and

```
<a href="index-eng"><img id="english" src="images/english.png"></a>
```

I left the website like this so you can test it on my friends website [www.gester.nl](http://www.gester.nl).

Click back on forth on english button and then again on the dutch button.
Sometimes it works when you click on english and sometimes it doesnt when you click on the english and dutch button.

I really appreciate the help. Cause i was happy when it worked like for seconds and then i saw this problem that i couldn't fix now. Been looking and changing (default_page) and deleting some lines to look where the problem starts but i don't know how to work with this jquery code.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#english').click(function () {
        $.cookie('default_page', dutch_page, { expires: 999 });
        alert('Dutch was set as the default language');
    });
```

You're making it so no matter what that whenever you click Dutch or English, it'll set it to the dutch page still. Therefore, your default page cookie is trying to update to a new variable and it's continuously calling the old one. Try setting the English function to this:

```
$('#english').click(function () {
        $.cookie('default_page', english_page, { expires: 999 });
        alert('English was set as the default language');
    });
```

Could be wrong, but I'm just curious as to what that does. Pretty sure that could be causing something though.

Comment: On top of this answer, through further inspection of the website you gave us. In the script.js file, you aren't closing you addEventListener for the click function.

Comment: That doesn't work. it's weird becaouse if i remove this code:

<code> if ($.cookie('default_page') != null) {
        if (window.location.href != url + '/' + $.cookie('default_page')) {
            window.location.href = url + '/' + $.cookie('default_page');
        }
    }
<code>

Comment: When i remove that code everything works fine except that it doesn't remember the page. I already tried to change this code a little without succes. Do you maybe understand how to change this code in the proper manner? Thanks for your time

Comment: I kept the code online. You can still observe it at www.gester.nl (still keeps flickering)

Comment: Do you know why this is? I am really dying to know this. Tried everything

Answer (score 0):

With my answer above, also do this.

In your script.js file, change this:

```
document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("my_form").className="submitted";
});
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", function()){
document.getElementById("my_form").className="submitted";
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time and your answer. If i change this code the website doesn't show my nothing anymore (white or only background).

Comment: On line 108 of script.js in the /script/ folder. You never updated what I said above. At least not on gester.nl. Once you update line 108, make sure to upload it to Gester.nl so I can inspect further into the problem.

Comment: @GiovanniPaez read above, was just trying to get your attention here.

Comment: Yes brother i changed it but it changes nothing. That's not the source of the problem. I am really going crazy with this code, been trying it to fix it for 2/3 day's. I found out that the cookie that gets saved is getting saved double so the saved cookie of both english and dutch loads again and again and again flickering. So i am busy to find a way to remove the cookie, which doesn't help because it doesn't delete the cookie number 2 which is on the other page, it only deletes cookie number 1 which is on the same page. It don't know what to do, can you help me with this?

Comment: And changing the above code gives me a white page again, so that code is fine. Let's focus on the script code from lanuage pages

Comment: I fixed it by simply deleting the cookie again